# ios application submission query

Tags: iphone, ios

I have not submitted an application yet, however am wondering if you guys could share your knowledge and experience on the subject and tell me if my plans will work or not.

The app I have created has a registration process in the app itself that updates the applications cookie which keeps it registered. Thus in its initial stages the application will be locked and the user will then have to register on my site which will be a subscription based payment to keep the phone working.

Do you think apple will allow this? if not what suitable alternative are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be fine as long as you follow the review tips:

**Providing Additional Info for the App Review Process**

If your application requires specific settings, user registrations or account information prior to submission to the App Store, be sure to include that info in the field "Demo Account - Full Access" on iTunes Connect. This is a text field visible only to the App Review team, so the information entered in that field will not be viewable on iTunes to the general public. You can also include general instructions or other relevant information about your application which you think would be useful for the review process.

Comment: Okay cool! I have been doing a ton of reading but their is just so many different things to comprehend its abit overwhelming.